# Add another routes within dynamic Route in nextjs 14

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

Guy I came across a scenario where i need project id that is dynamic , For management/123 that take me to dashboard of that project that shows stats about the project, well the problem is i have to show feature and issues pages as well that are another routes same for create feature and create issue

Is there any way we can do something like this

/management/123/issues
/management/123/features etc

But when i place features folder inside management/[id]/page.tsx and feature issues folder it show you cant you other routes with in dynamic route also document says

Dynamic routes must have page.tsx file not any other routes

Whats the best solution for my problem or anyway to get this done

All i need is project id , when i am at features pages as well as feature detail page or create feature page as the user the interacts to make some changes i have to use project id to make change in backend

If you need more details i am happy to provide

[image: Folder structure Overview]

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :**

**Solution :**

> You need to do nesting of dynamic routes.

**Inshort :**

Your folder structure should be something like this :

```
│       ├── management
│       │   ├── page.js
│       │   └── [mid]
│       │       ├── features
│       │       │   ├── create-feature
│       │       │   │   └── page.js
│       │       │   ├── page.js
│       │       │   └── [fid]
│       │       │       └── page.js
│       │       ├── issues
│       │       │   ├── create-issue
│       │       │   │   └── page.js
│       │       │   ├── page.js
│       │       │   └── [issueid]
│       │       │       └── page.js
│       │       └── page.js
```

By using above folder structure you will get URLs like :

- http://localhost:3000/management
- http://localhost:3000/management/1 (project id : 1)
- http://localhost:3000/management/1/features (Shows all features for project id : 1)
- http://localhost:3000/management/1/features/create-feature (Create new feature for project id : 1 )
- http://localhost:3000/management/1/features/Feature3 (Shows feature id 3 for project id : 1)
- http://localhost:3000/management/1/issues (Shows all Issues for project id : 1)
- http://localhost:3000/management/1/features/create-issue (Create new Issue for project id : 1 )
- http://localhost:3000/management/1/issues/Issue3 (Shows issue id 3 for project id : 1)

**Code :**

> ***Please make necessary changes wherever required, code is kept as small as possible***

**page.js** under `app\management\page.js` :

```
import Link from "next/link";

export default function ManagementPage() {
    const Projects = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Management</h1>
            <h3>All Projects : </h3>
            <ul>
                {
                    Projects.map((v, i) => (
                        <li key={i}>
                            <Link href={'management/' + v}>
                                Project {v}
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    ))
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Project Dashboard** under `app\management\[mid]\page.js` :

```
import Link from "next/link";
export default function Dashboard({ params }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Dashboard</h1>
            <h3>Management of Project : {params.mid}</h3>
            <Link href={"/management/" + params.mid + "/features"}>Features of {params.mid}</Link>

            <br />

            <Link href={"/management/" + params.mid + "/issues"}>Issues of {params.mid}</Link>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**All Features Page** under `app\management\[mid]\features\page.js` *(I have kept Create features page link here )* :

```
import Link from 'next/link'
const Features = ({ params }) => {
    const AllFeatures = ["Feature1", "Feature2", "Feature3", "Feature4"]
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Features page for Project {params.mid}</h1>
            <p>All Features of Project {params.mid}</p>

            {/*  GET FEATURES BY ID, USING API CALL */}

            <ul>
                {
                    AllFeatures.map((v, i) => (
                        <li key={i}>
                            <Link href={"/management/" + params.mid + "/features/" + v}>{v} </Link>
                        </li>
                    ))
                }
            </ul>

            <Link href={"/management/" + params.mid + "/features/create-feature"}>+ Create Features</Link>

        </div>
    )
}
export default Features
```

**Feature detail by FeatureID**  under `app\management\[mid]\features\[fid]\page.js` :

```
const FeatureDetailsPage = ({ params }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Features Details Page </h1>
            <h3>Features details of Project {params.mid}</h3>
            <p>Feature ID {params.fid}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
export default FeatureDetailsPage
```

**Create Feature Page** under `app\management\[mid]\features\page.js` :

```
const CreateFeaturePg = ({ params }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Create Feature Page </h1>
            <p>Create Features for Project {params.mid}</p>
            <h3>Add Feature for Project {params.mid}</h3>
            <input type="text" placeholder='Feature Name' />
            <button>Add Feature</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CreateFeaturePg
```

**All Issues page** under `app\management\[mid]\issues\page.js` *(I have kept Create Issues page link here )* :

```
import Link from 'next/link'
const IssuesPage = ({ params }) => {
    const AllIssues = ["Issue1", "Issue2", "Issue3", "Issue4"]
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Issues Page for Project {params.mid}</h1>
            <ul>
                {
                    AllIssues.map((v, i) => (
                        <li key={i}>
                            <Link href={"/management/" + params.mid + "/issues/" + v}>{v} </Link>
                        </li>
                    ))
                }
            </ul>
            <Link href={"/management/" + params.mid + "/features/create-issue"}>+ Create Issues</Link>

        </div>
    )
}
export default IssuesPage
```

**Issues Details Page** under `app\management\[mid]\issues\[issueid]\page.js` :

```
const IssueDetailsPage = ({ params }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Issues Details Page </h1>
            <h3>Issues details of Project {params.mid}</h3>
            <p>Issue ID {params.issueid}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
export default IssueDetailsPage
```

**Create Issues Page** under `app\management\[mid]\issues\create-issue\page.js`:

```
const CreateIssuePg = ({ params }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Create Issue Page </h1>
            <p>Create Issues for Project {params.mid}</p>
            <h3>Add Issue for Project {params.mid}</h3>
            <input type="text" placeholder='Issue Name' />
            <button>Add Issue</button>
        </div>
    )
}
export default CreateIssuePg
```

***Please Read :***

- Dynamic Routes : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes

> ***If you still have any doubts leave a comment.***

Comment: thanks, it was hard to find this specific use case and while this is indeed the solution, it kind of socks to have all files called "page" . I'd much better like to have `issues/[id]/page.js` , `issues/[id]/edit.js`, `issues/[id]/otheraction.js` and so on